# Weird CSS margin behavior - browser not displaying small margins properly

Tags: html, css

I'm in an fix. I have got six featured posts (images) that I want to appear like this---

http://media.prothug.com/2013/05/wpid-featt1.png

But I get this

http://media.prothug.com/2013/05/wpid-Featured1.png

I do not and cannot, and I have tried a lot of things, understand why there is that empty space between the "li" and the "ul".

This is the html that I have got for the featured images---

```
<div id="featured-boxes">
<ul class="featured-boxes-ul">
<li>
<a href="http://example.com">
<img src="lemon.jpg" alt="Featured Post 1" />
<p class="featured-boxes-caption">Little Johnny</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://example.com">
<img src="lemon.jpg" alt="Featured Post 2" />
<p class="featured-boxes-caption">Shrieking Banshee</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://example.com">
<img src="lemon.jpg" alt="Featured Post 3" />
<p class="featured-boxes-caption">Little Johnny</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://example.com">
<img src="lemon.jpg" alt="Featured Post 4" />
<p class="featured-boxes-caption">Shrieking Banshee</p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://example.com">
<img src="lemon.jpg" alt="Featured Post 5" />
<p class="featured-boxes-caption">Little Johnny </p>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://example.com">
<img src="lemon.jpg" alt="Featured Post 6" />
<p class="featured-boxes-caption">Shrieking Banshee</p>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And this is the css for it---

```
#featured-boxes {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 2em;
}
.featured-boxes-ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background:#777;
}
.featured-boxes-ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 32.7%;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin: 0.3em 0;
}
.featured-boxes-ul li:nth-child(2), .featured-boxes-ul li:nth-child(5) {
    margin-left: 0.95%;
    margin-right: 0.95%;
}
.featured-boxes-ul a {
    display: block;
    outline: 0;
}
.featured-boxes-ul a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.featured-boxes-ul img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
.featured-boxes-caption {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-indent: 30px;
    background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Wjvd/

The width of the "li" elements and the left and right margins around 2nd and 5th "li" elements add up to a total of 100%. 
I have tried everything I can and I know for sure that the "ul" does not have any padding on the right side. If I make the "li" smaller and make the margins of the 2nd and 5th "li" children really large, like say 10%, the whole featured images occupy the whole "div" without leaving any empty space between the images and the "ul". The problem seems to be that the browser(s) cannot calculate the small margins accurately.

Is there anything wrong with my css? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The two links above are dead

Comment: You're showing margins at percentages (and ems).  Depending on your outer size, `0.95%`might be smaller than the screen can handle.  Browsers don't handle a fraction of a pixel well.  It will not blend an edge like Photoshop.  Without seeing more (Please make a fiddle) You might just have to live with it

Comment: since the two images are not displayed in you post, I tried pasting your code in a fiddle and all seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Jhxpb/ Or am I missing something? Did you reset/normalize your css first?

Comment: I have edited the image links.

Comment: @ntgCleaner the outer container is 960px wide. So I think 0.95% is not too small; it's about 9px.

Comment: @PeterVR I have edited the image links. Please review the question again. I ope this time, my question is clearer. Thanks.

Comment: aah, your images help.

Comment: What browser are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/Jhxpb/ shows you code and I don't see any padding/margin on the right side... (Chrome on mac)

Comment: I am using Chrome on Windows. Also tried on Opera Mobile and Dolphin on Android tablet and phone.

Comment: the space on the right is small, but it's there.

Comment: please check my website. The real thing without jsfiddle. prothugdotcom

Comment: @DavidHeisnam is your container always 960px wide?  If so, why are you using percentages? added a fiddle to my answer below

Comment: @ntgCleaner, actually I am using responsive design (which I have turned off at the moment) . On a tablet, the image sizes will change so that there will be two images on each row.

Comment: @PeterVR there's space on the right in your jsfiddle. :/ How could percentage margins be a cause of such trouble? Why, oh Why? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's a few things:

1. Why are you using `<li>` elements?  are you able to just use `<div>`s?
2. There's a few approaches for this.  But just using CSS floats may not work for you.  Even though your math is perfectly correct, as I stated above, the browser can not do a fraction of a pixel.  If you were to float these perfectly and you still got the margins to work, every once in a while, your far right image would push down as if it were floating around the other two.

You could float the third element to the right and not have a margin after the second one.  If you do your math right, you can get this to look proper, but you may still have unequal margins if you do this. (here's the fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/WZXa4/)

Comment: I think that approach (floating the third element to the right), is the best solution. I don't think the table approach can work on responsive design.

Comment: It looks like a list of images to me, what value would divs have over a list?

Comment: Oh, and why do you ask about my usage of     <li> instead of     <div> ? Is     <li> sort of troublesome?

Comment: @DavidHeisnam I only ask because usually list items are reserved for just that - list items.  I understand you are listing them and honestly it makes no difference when the outcome is the same.  I was just wondering if it was useful for you for the markup

Answer (score 0):

Mixing units can be problematic, especially if margins are involved (otherwise you could just use `box-sizing: border-box` and not worry about it.  If your goal is to have your elements be responsive, my recommendation is to use the CSS Multicolumn module:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/txvon6wq

```
#featured-boxes {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 2em;
}
.featured-boxes-ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background:#777;
  columns: 15em;
  column-gap: 1em;
}
.featured-boxes-ul li {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin: 0.3em 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.featured-boxes-ul li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.featured-boxes-ul a {
    display: block;
    outline: 0;
}
.featured-boxes-ul a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.featured-boxes-ul img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
.featured-boxes-caption {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-indent: 30px;
    background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Flexbox can also be used for this purpose, but browser support is low due to the fact that not all browsers that support Flexbox support `flex-wrap: wrap`.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/iHGCd

```
.gallery {
  margin: -5px;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  .gallery {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.gallery img {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

http://caniuse.com/flexbox